# How to change date format from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyymm?

Tags: sql-server

Please help with converting my date code to give output in YYYYMM format.

```
select convert (date,DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,GETDATE()) + 1, -1))  as lastDayOfPrevYear
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS ( DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()) - 1, 1, 1 ) as firstDayOfPrevYear
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) as firstDayOfCurrentYear
```

Comment: FYI, date doesn't have format, it's a binary data

Comment: `Date`, `DateTime`, and `DateTime2` types do not have a format and are not stored as a formatted string. You only perceive a format because you are human so the default display shows you the value formatted in ISO8601 notation. The displayed format is not a concern of the persistence layer, it is a concern for the presentation layer where the value is rendered for a human to see it.

Comment: select convert(varchar(6), getdate(), 112) is the fastest way, the format function performs awfull

Answer (score 5):

Dates do not have a format, but you can create a string or even an int as yyyymm

**Example**

```
Select convert(varchar(6),getdate(),112)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `FORMAT` function like this

```
SELECT
    MyDate = GETDATE(),
    mmddyyyy = FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMddyyyy'),
    YYYYMM = FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMM')
```

Comment: If you care about performance, then you'll avoid using `FORMAT()`

Comment: Format has some great functionality, but it should come with a "caution sticker"  If not used sparingly... performance can suffer

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),112);
the answer is "201907"

Comment: Actually, the answer is 20190711 when you don't set the varchar size.  Furthermore, posting duplicate answers may attract down-votes.